# Назначение OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, button, android-on-click, android-button

Доброго времени суток.

Есть MainActivity реализующая интерфейс `View.OnClickListener`, соответственно есть метод `OnClick` типа такого:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.btnDel){   //Кнопка Удалить
        Button btnDel = (Button) v;
        btnDel.setText("Отмена");
        btnDel.setOnClickListener(oclBtnDelWhileDel);
```

Выше по коду я создаю `oclBtnDelWhileDel` таким:

```
View.OnClickListener oclBtnDelWhileDel = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button btnDel = (Button) v;
        btnDel.setText("Удалить");
        btnDel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
} ;
```

Идея в том что метод `OnClick` класса назначает кнопке слушателя `oclBtnDelWhileDel`, а `oclBtnDelWhileDel` назначает слушателем обратно метод `OnClick`.

Проблема в том, что при первом нажатии на кнопку, она меняет название на "Отмена" и назначается слушатель `oclBtnDelWhileDel`.

А вот при втором нажатии на кнопку название меняется на "Удалить", а вот слушатель обратно не меняется.

Через дебаггер выполняется опять код `oclBtnDelWhileDel`.

**Вопрос:** не могу понять, почему?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnClickListener` "прикрепляется" к определенной кнопке, и реализует метод обратного вызова (`Callback`), проще говоря, когда вы нажимаете на кнопку - происходит некоторое действие.

Конкретно в вашей реализации очень много некрасивых мест, начиная с объявления кнопки при нажатии на другую кнопку - заканчивая установлением слушателя кнопки внутри реализации `onClick` другой кнопки.

Вы можете просто менять динамически текст на кнопке, и выполнять тот, или иной функционал, допустим:

```
if(btn.getText().equals("Удалить")){

// происходит операция удаления
} else {

//операция отмены.

}
```

Написано на коленке, и вероятно, ответ выше помог более по теме, но и этим не пренебрегайте.

Зарефакторите код, станет легче.

Comment: Да, код действительно не красивый и с самого начала не правильно спроектированный. Рефакторить не выгодно т.к. осталось реализовать очень небольшой функционал. Спасибо за интересный вариант реализации.

Comment: @slaker1990 'btnDel.setOnClickListener(new MainActivity);' это ваш код?

Comment: Бред конечно, но я его попробовал. Если точнее то `new MainActivity()` .

Comment: @slaker1990 в `android` все устроено чуть иначе: активити это самостоятельный элемент, который относится к другим "законам" создания и переходам. Аналог создания `new MainActivity()` будет следующее: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 5):

```
View.OnClickListener oclBtnDelWhileDel = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button btnDel = (Button) v;
        btnDel.setText("Удалить");
        btnDel.setOnClickListener(this); //Вот тут ошибка
    }
} ;
```

В данном случае `this` указывает не на внешний класс, а на `View.OnClickListener`, таким образом вы устаналиваете слушателем его же самого

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь правда не знаю как мне поставить слушателя класс. `btnDel.setOnClickListener(MainActivity);` ругается. `btnDel.setOnClickListener(new MainActivity);` выдает ошибку на третий клик.

Comment: `setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this)`